# How to use elif with && and -o in a bash script properly

Tags: bash, if-statement

Bash version 4.4.20
Ubuntu 16.04

I need to compare time and extensions for a particular project I have. Below is something similar to what I am trying to do but the error is the same. I am not sure where exactly the error is as shellcheck is not producing one.

```
#!/bin/bash
#

while read -r filename; do
  extension="${filename##*.}"
  if [ "$extension" == "zip" ] && [ "$filename" == "one.zip" ]; then
    echo "Filename is $filename"
  elif [ "$extension" == "zip" ] && [ "$filename" == "file_1.zip" ] -o [ "$filename" == "file_2.zip" ] -o [ "$filename" == "file_3.zip" ]; then
    echo "Filename is $filename"
  elif [ "$extension" == "csv" ] && [ "$filename" == "two.csv" ]; then
    echo "Filename is $filename"
  else
    echo "Filename is $filename"
  fi
done<fileList.txt
```

Error:

```
Filename is one.zip
check.sh: line 8: [: too many arguments
Filename is file_1.zip
check.sh: line 8: [: too many arguments
Filename is file_2.zip
check.sh: line 8: [: too many arguments
Filename is file_3.zip
Filename is two.csv
Filename is three.sql
```

Comment: Try to replace `-o` with `||`. You can also write one statement like this `[ ... -a ... -o ... -o ...]`.

Comment: Both `-a` and `-o` are considered obsolete (as they introduce ambiguities into your code) and non-portable.

Comment: You don't need to check the extension separately. For example, if the extension is *not* "zip", `[ "$filename" = one.zip ]` is guaranteed to fail anyway.

Comment: @chepner: Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use pattern matching to your advantage:

```
while IFS= read -r filename; do
  if [[ "$filename" = one.zip ]; then
    echo "Filename is $filename"
  elif [[ "$filename" = file_[123].zip ]; then
    echo "Filename is $filename"
  elif [[ "$filename" = two.csv ]; then
    echo "Filename is $filename"
  else
    echo "Filename is $filename"
  fi
done < fileList.txt
```

A `case` statement will work in *any* POSIX shell, not just a shell that supports a `bash`-like `[[ ... ]]` command.

```
while IFS= read -r filename; do
  case $filename in
    one.zip) echo "Filename is $filename" ;;
    file_[123].zip) echo "..." ;;
    two.csv) echo "..." ;;
    *) echo "..." ;;
  esac
done
```

To match a range of years(?), you can use

```
case $value in
  200[0-9]|201[0-9]|202[0-1]) echo "Year between 2000 and 2021" ;;
esac
```

You can't do that as simply with `[[ value = ... ]]`, since the `|` is part of the `case` statement's syntax, not an alternation operator in the pattern. Instead, you would need multiple match operators:

```
if [[ $value = 200[0-9] || $value = 201[0-19] || $value = 202[0-1] ]]; then
```

Comment: Nice POSIX shell solution.

Comment: @chepner That case statement is pretty clean. On your fourth line, if the filenames were so_2001_1.zip, so_2002_1.zip, so_2003_1.zip, so_2004_1.zip, so_2005_1.zip, and the naming convention continued to so_2021_1.zip, how would that case look?

Comment: There are a few possibilities. POSIX patterns are not *quite* as powerful as regular expressions; `so_*_1.zip` would match the desired files, but also additional ones. If you knew exactly how many digits you would want to match, you could go with `so_????_1.zip` or more specifically (but far more verbosely) `so_[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]_1.zip`.

Comment: Going back to regular expressions, `if [[ $filename =~ so_[[:digit:]]{4}_1\.zip ]]; then` would match exactly the desired files.

Comment: So your line four would be ```so_[[:2000:]][[:2001:]][[:2002:]][[:2003:]][[:2004:]][[:2005:]][[:2006:]][[:2007:]][[:2008:]][[:2009:]][[:2010:]][[:2011:]][[:2012:]][[:2013:]][[:2014:]][[:2015:]][[:2016:]][[:2017:]][[:2018:]][[:2019:]][[:2020:]][[:2021:]]_1.zip) echo "...";;```

Comment: No; you can't simply put an arbitrary literal value between `[[:` and `:]]`. `[...]` is a bracket expression, inside of which you can use a character class like `[:digit:]`. `[[:digit:]]` is then a generalization of `[0-9]`. If you wanted to hardcode the 22 values shown, see the updated answer.

Comment: Even thou Mathias answered me correctly, I do like learning shorter ways to accomplish the same task. I'm going to use your method. Surely appreciate it.

Comment: FYI, if you were interested in trying out `zsh`, it has a richer set of glob operators. You can write `if [[ $value = 2<000-021> ]]` to match a numeric range.

Answer (score 3):

Here an explanation for *why* you get this error, as you get already good answers on how to do it correctly:

Note that the command `[` is equivalent to `test`, hence your line 8 in effect (also removing unnecessary quotes) contains:

```
elif test "$extension" == zip ] && test "$filename" == file_1.zip ] -o [ "$filename" == file_2.zip ] -o [ "$filename" == file_3.zip ]
```

From the *test* man-page, we can see that the closing `]` is optional, but if it is present, it terminates the expression to be tested.

The first `test`, which is just

```
test "$extension" == "zip" ]
```

is fine in this respect, but the second one starts with

```
test "$filename" == file_1.zip ] -o [  ...
```

Hence, when parsing the arguments, `test` encounters a `]` and knows that this is the terminator for the arguments, but then finds another argument (`-o`), and doesn't know what to do with it. Hence it complains that it has got *too many arguments*

Comment: `test` does not allow a trailing `]` argument, nor does it (in general; that's a `bash` extension) use `==` for string equality comparison.

Comment: @user1934428 Surely appreciate the time you took to explain this to me. Hats off to you mate.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the syntax to what I *think* is the modern bash idioms. The script now works. Please correct me if I missed something else :

```
#!/bin/bash
#

while read -r filename
do
  extension="${filename##*.}"
  if [[ "$extension" = "zip" &&  "$filename" = "one.zip" ]]
  then
    echo "Filename is $filename"
  elif [[ "$extension" = "zip" && "$filename" = "file_1.zip" ]] \
  || [[ "$filename" = "file_2.zip" ]] \
  || [[ "$filename" = "file_3.zip" ]]
  then
    echo "Filename is $filename"
  elif [[ "$extension" = "csv" && "$filename" = "two.csv" ]]
  then
    echo "Filename is $filename"
  else
    echo "Filename is $filename"
  fi
done < fileList.txt
```

Regards!

Comment: You did answer my question and this was exactly what I was looking for. Hats off to you mate.